# Is it haram to take and save digital photographs in islam?

Tags: halal-haram, photos

I read somewhere that photography is haram in Islam, but i am little bit confused about digital photography.   Can someone explain the situation to me in detail?

Is it haram to take and save digital photographs in islam?

Comment: Places to start researching the topic are 1. [Is drawing or photographing people prohibited in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/869/17163), 2. [Can I use pictures on a website?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2928/17163), 3. [Is it permissible to photograph nature?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38088/17163).

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model I strongly recommend you to take our [tour] and check our [help].